# Batch move photos to other folder in Lightroom 3

Tags: lightroom, file-management

Currently I have my photos organised in Events in Lightroom 3. It also uses a folder structure that looks like this:

> Year/dd-mm/Eventname-##.jpg

I figured that it would be easier for me to find a photo in the folder structure (in case I end up without Lightroom somehow) if I would use an event-based structure instead of date-based. So I want my structure to look like this:

> Eventname/year/dd-mm/Eventname-##.jpg

How can I change this for +/- 50 events in Lightroom?

Edit:

Just to clarify:
The events are all in separate collections in Lightroom. So I have a collection called "Birthday" where all the photos are for the birthday event. I am looking for a way to say to Lightroom: "put all the photos from a certain collection in a folder conforming to the above mentioned structure".
So the filename of the actual photo has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way Lightroom can be used to read part of a filename and then create folders based on that and move the files into those folders. But if you're only talking about 50 folders it might not take long to create them and drag-and-drop the content in, especially if each event is on a separate date and therefore easy to isolate.

If you're looking at too many folders to manually create, or if there are multiple events on each day then I would consider scripting the creation and moving of the folders using your operating system, but you would still have to manually update the location of the folders in Lightroom

Answer (score 0):

As @Rick says Lightroom doesn't have built-in support for directly moving images into the folder structure you want. However if the images have the correct creation date in their EXIF data you could export each collection of images to the parent (Eventname) folder and then import them into your catalog again with the import dialog set to organize by date and Lightroom would automatically handle the year/dd-mm part for you.